# How to reloadData() in ViewController #1 after ViewController #2 is dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, tableview, dismiss

i am new to iOS here is my question:

I have a saveCardViewController (Presented Modally) with some textFields and Save button.

```
@IBAction func Save(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    date = datePicker.date
    
    try! realm.write() {
        
        sessionCard.pokerType = pokerTypeSegment.titleForSegment(at: pokerTypeSegment.selectedSegmentIndex)!
        date = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        sessionCard.handsPlayed = Int(handPlayedTextlabel.text!) ?? 0
        sessionCard.moneyIn = Int(moneyInTextLabel.text!) ?? 0
        sessionCard.moneyOut = Int(moneyOutTextLabel.text!) ?? 0
        sessionCard.timePlayed = Int(timePlayedTextLabel.text!) ?? 0
        sessionCard.sortDate = date
        
        realm.add(sessionCard)
        
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How can I reloadData() on my main ViewController, after Save button is pressed and saveCardViewController is dismissed.

Thanks!

**EDIT # 1:**

Thank you @davidev for your answer,I made changes but still does not update

**My ViewController With TableView:**

```
class SessionViewController: BackgroundViewController, RefreshViewDelegate {


func refreshView() {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self       

}
```

**My ViewController with data and Save button:**

```
    protocol RefreshViewDelegate {
    func refreshView()
}

class AddSessionViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    var delegate: RefreshViewDelegate?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
               
        
    }

 @IBAction func TEST2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        delegate?.refreshView()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
```

Comment: NotificationCenter/ delegate pattern or callback

Comment: I upvoted @davidev answer because he focused on using delegation. The only issue with Notifications - they will work - is where delegation is 1:1 (meaning your `saveCardViewController` is tightly tied to the VC presenting it) Notifications are not (they send it to the first receiver subscribed to it). As for using a callback? I'm not sure, but it doesn't sound like it fits what you want.

Comment: i edit my question can you guys look pls @davidev

Comment: It looks good. But show use the code where you open the child view modally. There, where you create the child view, you have to set the delegate. 
let vc = AddSessionViewController() and then vc.delegate = self

Comment: @davidev i think i am doing something wrong because i connected views like this https://prnt.sc/vjp9al

Comment: As you are using storyboard segues, you can override performSegue function in your main view controller and then set the delegate. I updated my answer, hope it helps, spasibo))

Comment: We made it!!  @davidev Spasibo very much!)

Comment: Great to hear))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `delegate` pattern to achieve this.

Declare your Refresh Protocol like this:

```
protocol RefreshViewDelegate {
    func refreshView()
}
```

Make your parent view conform to this protocol and implement refreshView() with your custom refresh action. Also make sure to set the delegate of the child view to self.

Inside `saveCardViewController` declare your delegate variable

```
var delegate : RefreshViewDelegate?
```

And call the delegate action inside your IBaction

```
delegate?.refreshView()
```

**Edit:**

I just saw your updated code. As you are using Storyboard segues, you still have to set the delegate via code. In your main view controller add the function:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? AddSessionViewController
    {
        viewController.delegate = self
    }
}
```